# How to calculate the euclidian norm of each vector in a list and add to a new list using numpy in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list L that is full of vectors, I want to calculate the norm of each of these vectors And add the values to a new list N.

I did the following (problem is it returns a single value.. instead of a list of values with all the different norms ) what should i add?

```
N = list() 
from numpy import linalg as LA
N.append(LA.linalg.norm(L,ord=None))
print(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code `LA.linalg.norm(L,ord=None)` calculates a single norm value for the entire list of vectors.  To calculate separate norms for each vector in your `L` list, you should loop over that list and append each result to the `N` list, e.g.,

```
N = list() 
from numpy import linalg as LA
for vector in L:
   N.append(LA.linalg.norm(vector,ord=None))
print(N)
```

Comment: That makes sense unfortunately when i now print N it still gives the same single value.... Could this have to do something with my list L? I printed L and get my vectors looking like this: (vertically but this comment puts it all on one line) (this is the bottom bit of the list... 

[[ 9],
        [  3],
        [ 3],
        [4]],

       [[ 2],
        [  8],
        [  4],
        [1]],

       [[ 4],
        [  7],
        [  8],
        [8]],

       [[ 7],
        [  1],
        [  3,
        [7]],
 
       [[ 8 ],
        [  8],
        [  4 ],
        [1 ]]])]

Comment: what is one vector in this list? [[ 9], [ 3], [ 3], [4]], is that one?

Comment: Yes, then the structure of this L list will not work for this loop.  You have two extra square brackets at the end and one brace.  And each individual component of your vectors is in its own list.  I think you'll want to transform it so it's just one list of lists, with components of one vector combined into one list (or some other type of array).  You can look up ways to merge/join lists.

Comment: the "extra" brackets is because i copy pasted only a bottom part of my full list so they do actually match up with ones in the start of the list. I have found a way to merge every value into one list seperated by a comma but i still want to keep the them seperated as vectors. Could you help me with that: this is the code : import re                   results = [int(i) for i in re.findall('\d+', (str(L)))]
   print(results)

Comment: It actually changed the values all the -values are missing and there seem to be more values now mmm that code might not do it.

Comment: actually my list L looks like it consists of matrices shouldn't the function lin.alg.norm etc just work for that too? I mean clearly it does not but something to think about i guess

Comment: Look at the documentation for [numpy.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html).  It says it accepts 'axis' argument along with the data.  You can use it to specify the axis of your full matrix along which it should compute the vector norms.